# High DPI Scaling WinForms Panel Control Not Scaling

Tags: c#, winforms, dpi, highdpi

I have an application built with Winforms, I am on a laptop which has a very high resolution. As my application was appearing blurry I have turned on High DPI scaling using `SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)`. This fixes the issue with my window being blurry, but my controls with-in the window are not scaling.

I have a single panel control, that I had set to **Dock: Fill**. Instead of filling my entire application width/height, it only scales to the non-scaled size of my application. I have used a tool called AutoIt & iSpy to analyze my client, and when using this I can see that the panel has not scaled.

[image: photo of size of my client]

As you can see, the panel size is 659W, 507H which is not the dimensions of the application & also you can see by the highlighted panel that it's not scaled to fill. **Is there any way for me to correctly scale the panel?**

Comment: Make you application DpiAware from the start. See here: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) (note that the some settings apply to newer version of Windows and some to older ones. Also, the `app.manifest` settings, if any, override the `app.config` settings - mixing these two plus some Win32 API call is some kind of *art*). See also [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)

Comment: You need to design your app to be *scalable*. Anchoring and docking need to be applied wisely, TableLayoutPanels (watch out when you nest these, you must control the internal padding and the margins of child controls) and FlowLayoutPanels are of great help. Make your Forms scale to DPI, not Font, but you also need to handle Font scaling. And a lot of testing, at least until you get the hang of it.